# In which lifecycle method should I perform a second depending request for a data in React?

Tags: reactjs

A legacy component is requesting a some data at componentWillMount (I know that this should not be done here, and at this point refactoring is not permited). Once I received this data I need to perform a second request with data from the first one. But when componentDidMount hits, the data is not available.

I can't a way more/less dirty/clean to re-render.

I just wonder is refactor in this scenario is the only option?

Thanks

Comment: What does the legacy component do with the data it requests? If it does something like storing the data in state, then `componentWillUpdate` is probably the most appropriate place

Comment: Yes, but I need to trigger the re-render, which doesn't appear to be the case for componentWillUpdate

Comment: Do you need to trigger a re-render or do you need to perform a second request, or both?

Comment: I need to perform the second request, then re-render with the result state/props of the second request...

Comment: Then `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: It might help if you were to provide sample of your existing code or the legacy component is working to understand better

Answer (score 0):

In componentWillReceiveProps, if nextProps has the response to the request you made then you make the next request.
Edit: or in componentWillUpdate if you're just storing the data in the local state

Comment: nextProps,should have the first request ? Because is not hitting componentWillReceiveProps... and that might be, because the first request wasn't properly placed on componentDidMOunt? So, back again, only option is refactor?

Comment: It will only hit componentWillReceiveProps if you are storing data in props like when you use redux, which I probably wrongly assumed you were. ComponentWillUpdate should work, and if you want to re-render you have to change the state somehow, so store the second request result in your component state. It shouldn't be necessary to change to componentDidMount

Comment: Actually, we do use redux. It seems that there is a dirty trick in another component that sets a 'redundant' state just to modify it. But now that you mention it, it seems like that's the way